# Why am I getting "ق" instead of "fi"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, character-encoding

I extracted text from a document and I noted the text has some unknown characters, like:

```
"An adversary modiقes the aggregation result"
```

It is clear ق is not the real character and should be replace with "fi" - and there are other, similar examples.

Can I replace these characters with the correct English characters using python?

I write the follwing code for extract and decode the text streams from pdf file:

```
import zlib

file = open ("PDF_File.pdf"."rb").read()  # read pdf file
objectPDF = re.findall('(\d+ \d+ obj.+?endobj)',file , re.DOTALL) # extract pdf 
                                                                   # objects
for item in objectPDF :
    pdfstreams = re.findall('stream(.*?)endstream',item  , re.DOTALL) # extract text 
                                                                      # stream 
                                                                      # encoded by                     
                                                                   # flatedecode filter
for item in pdfstreams :                                          
    buffer = item  
    decomp = zlib.decompress(buffer)   # decode each stream
    pdf_txt = open("Txt_PDF.txt","w")  
    pdf_txt .write(decomp)             # write the text to file
    pdf_txt .close()
```

Comment: Of course you can. Now it depends on how you do that.

Comment: The question is, *why* did the decoding of the source material give you these strange characters?  What encoding is the source in?  Maybe you're reading it incorrectly.  Can you give us a snippet of the original material?

Comment: try replace if you use utf-8 #coding=utf-8
a = u'An adversary modiقes the aggregation result'
print a.replace(u'ق','fi')

Comment: I extracted the text from pdf file, the stream encoded by flate decode  filter. I decoded it using zlib library in python and got this result

Answer (score 3):

You have an encoding error:

```
>>> print u"modiقes".encode("cp1256").decode("mac_roman")
modiﬁes
```

Notice that the offending character is not the result of mangling the pair of characters `fi` but of mangling the single character `ﬁ` ([U+FB01 'LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb01/index.htm)).

Without seeing your code it's impossible to say *exactly* how this happened, but it boils down to: you tried to decode [Mac OS Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) text as [Windows 1256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256). If you stop doing that, you should stop having the problem.

Comment: @hobbs the first time I saw the word "macroman" I read it as "macro-man" instead of "mac-roman", and I was really confused.